# Font sizes in new theorem style?

Tags: theorems, fontsize

I would like to produce a new theorem style such that the text in the body is `10pt`, instead of `11pt` (size of the document).

I tried adding `10pt` for the body font, but does not compile:

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}  % Name
{3pt}       % Space above 
{3pt}       % Space below
{10pt}      % Body font
{}          % Indent amount 
{\scshape}  % Theorem head font
{.}         % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}      % Space after theorem head
{}          % Theorem head spec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\small` instead. In `\documentclass[11pt]`, `\small` defaults to `10pt`; what you're after.